# Apply style to a unique spinner

Tags: android, styles, spinner

I would like to disable the default divider which separates items into a spinner.

I tried to create my own style

```
<style name="MyDropDownWithoutDivider" parent="Widget.Sherlock.TextView.SpinnerItem">
    <item name="android:dividerHeight">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:divider">@null</item>
    <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/selector_action_bar</item>
</style>
```

And apply it to my spinner

```
<Spinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        style="@style/MyDropDownWithoutDivider" />
```

But it does not work at all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this link select spinner style...!

http://android-holo-colors.com/

Save all drawable files,images,style and theme in your project..

then use it in your sipnner coding like this...

```
<Spinner 
     android:id="@+id/spinner"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="45dp"
     android:background="@drawable/spinner_background_holo_light"
     />
```